# TypeScript generation for SQL files

Tags: sql, typescript, apollo

I'm interested to know if anyone has come across a tool that can generate TypeScript type definitions based on the expected result of a SQL query? That is to say, is there a CLI that accepts a SQL schema and `.sql` file and outputs a `.ts` file based on the expected result of the query?

[Such a tool already exists for GraphQL queries](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen) and my team has found it extremely useful because it completely removes errors associated with hand-rolled type definitions.

Comment: Do you mean generating model based on SQL query?

Comment: @OPV see https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen. It transforms a GraphQL file into a type definition of the expected result.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, [PgTyped](https://github.com/adelsz/pgtyped) is a new tool that does that.
It allows you to generate TypeScript interfaces for raw SQL queries.

It works similarly to apollo-codegen, but instead of the `gql` tag you need to use a `sql` tag for your SQL queries.

It only supports PostgreSQL and is still in beta stage, but I am actively working on it and any contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

[sql-code-generator](https://github.com/uladkasach/sql-code-generator) is another option.

It does:

> - generating type definitions from SQL resources (e.g., tables, views, functions, procedures)
> - generating type definitions from SQL queries (e.g., select * from table)
> - generating typed functions that execute SQL queries from SQL queries (e.g., const sqlQueryFindAllUsersByName = async ({ input: InputType }): Promise)